# Concatenate multiple rows and fields in a table

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I want to concatenate fields intersected part of the same table

```
id      user_id     user_ip
4       971         108.54.218.114
5       972         108.54.218.114
6       973         108.54.218.114
7       974         108.54.218.114
8       975         107.222.159.246
9       975         98.54.818.133
```

In the example above, we can see that the user with the IP address (108.54.218.114) address to create multiple accounts with the following account IDs (971, 972, 973, 974), but also that the user with the account ID (975) is connect from the following IP addresses (107.222.159.246, 98.54.818.133)

I want to format the results like this

```
user_id             user_ip
971,972,973,974     108.54.218.114
975                 107.222.159.246, 98.54.818.133
```

MySQL

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users_log.user_id) AS ID_LOG, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT users_log.user_ip) AS IP_LOG
FROM users_log  
    GROUP BY users_log.user_id
ORDER BY users_log.user_id DESC
```

If anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: For sure you can do this, but usually you shouldn't even want to do this in sql. Relational Databases are designed to have atomic singular values in each cell. Grouping it like this should be done in your application logic.

Comment: What would the output be if there was another record `10, 975, 108.54.218.114`

Comment: @popovitsj I am forced to work with this structure

Comment: @AgRizzo it is unlikely!

Answer (score 0):

There is another recent question (which I can't find) on SO very close to this. I asked about the intersecting row because of the  (for lack of better term) *recursiveness* of this type of solution.

Here is SQL to give you your exact answer for that exact sample set.

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_ip) AS user_ip
FROM users_log
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
UNION
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id) AS user_id,  user_ip
FROM users_log
GROUP BY user_ip
HAVING COUNT(*) >1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help 

How to handle duplicates? eg. id 975 (here : http://pastebin.com/tnHvVnvy)